# Parallelize nested for loop in GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, tesseract, gnu-parallel

I have a small bash script to OCR PDF files (slightly modified [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR) script). The basic flow for each file is:

For each page in pdf FILE:

1. Convert page to TIFF image (imegamagick)
2. OCR image (tesseract)
3. Cat results to text file

Script:

```
FILES=/home/tgr/OCR/input/*.pdf
for f in $FILES
do

  FILENAME=$(basename "$f") 
  ENDPAGE=$(pdfinfo $f | grep "^Pages: *[0-9]\+$" | sed 's/.* //')
  OUTPUT="/home/tgr/OCR/output/${FILENAME%.*}.txt"
  RESOLUTION=1400
  touch $OUTPUT
  for i in `seq 1 $ENDPAGE`; do
      convert -monochrome -density $RESOLUTION $f\[$(($i - 1 ))\] page.tif
      echo processing file $f, page $i
      tesseract page.tif tempoutput -l ces
      cat tempoutput.txt >> $OUTPUT
  done

  rm tempoutput.txt
  rm page.tif
done
```

Because of high resolution and fact that tesseract can utilize only one core, the process is extremely slow (takes approx. 3 minutes to convert one PDF file).

Because I have thousands of PDF files I think I can use `parallel` to use all 4 cores, but I don't get the concept how to use it. In [examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__rewriting_nested_for_loops) I see:

```
Nested for-loops like this:

  (for x in `cat xlist` ; do
    for y in `cat ylist` ; do
      do_something $x $y
    done
  done) | process_output
can be written like this:

parallel do_something {1} {2} :::: xlist ylist | process_output
```

Unfortunately I was not able to figure out how to apply this. How do I parallelize my script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have 1000s of PDF files it is probably enough simply to parallelize the processing of PDF-files and not parallelize the processing of the pages in a single file.

```
function convert_func {
  f=$1
  FILENAME=$(basename "$f") 
  ENDPAGE=$(pdfinfo $f | grep "^Pages: *[0-9]\+$" | sed 's/.* //')
  OUTPUT="/home/tgr/OCR/output/${FILENAME%.*}.txt"
  RESOLUTION=1400
  touch $OUTPUT
  for i in `seq 1 $ENDPAGE`; do
      convert -monochrome -density $RESOLUTION $f\[$(($i - 1 ))\] $$.tif
      echo processing file $f, page $i
      tesseract $$.tif $$ -l ces
      cat $$.txt >> $OUTPUT
  done

  rm $$.txt
  rm $$.tif
}

export -f convert_func

parallel convert_func ::: /home/tgr/OCR/input/*.pdf
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial or http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). You command line
with love you for it.

Read the EXAMPLEs (`LESS=+/EXAMPLE: man parallel`).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

function convert_func {
    local FILE=$1 RESOLUTION=$2 PAGE_INDEX=$3 OUTPUT=$4
    local TEMP0=$(exec mktemp --suffix ".00.$PAGE_INDEX.tif")
    local TEMP1=$(exec mktemp --suffix ".01.$PAGE_INDEX")
    echo convert -monochrome -density "$RESOLUTION" "${FILE}[$(( PAGE_INDEX - 1 ))]" "$TEMP0"  ## Just for debugging purposes.
    convert -monochrome -density "$RESOLUTION" "${FILE}[$(( PAGE_INDEX - 1 ))]" "$TEMP0"
    echo "processing file $FILE, page $PAGE_INDEX"  ## I think you mean to place this before the line above.
    tesseract "$TEMP0" "$TEMP1" -l ces
    cat "$TEMP1".txt >> "$OUTPUT"  ## Lines may be mixed up from different processes here and a workaround may still be needed but it may no longer be necessary if outputs are small enough.
    rm -f "$TEMP0" "$TEMP1"
}

export -f convert_func

FILES=(/home/tgr/OCR/input/*.pdf)

for F in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    FILENAME=${F##*/}
    ENDPAGE=$(exec pdfinfo "$F" | grep '^Pages: *[0-9]\+$' | sed 's/.* //')
    OUTPUT="/home/tgr/OCR/output/${FILENAME%.*}.txt"
    RESOLUTION=1400
    touch "$OUTPUT"  ## This may no longer be necessary. Or probably you mean to truncate it instead e.g. : > "$OUTPUT"

    for (( I = 1; I <= ENDPAGE; ++I )); do
        printf "%s\xFF%s\xFF%s\xFF%s\x00" "$F" "$RESOLUTION" "$I" "$OUTPUT"
    done | parallel -0 -C $'\xFF' -j 4 -- convert_func '{1}' '{2}' '{3}' '{4}'
done
```

It exports a function that's importable by `parallel`, make proper sanitation of arguments, and unique temporary files to make parallel processing possible.

Update. This would hold output on multiple temporary files first before concatenating them to one main output file.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

function convert_func {
    local FILE=$1 RESOLUTION=$2 PAGE_INDEX=$3 OUTPUT=$4 TEMPLISTFILE=$5

    local TEMP_TIF=$(exec mktemp --suffix ".01.$PAGE_INDEX.tif")
    local TEMP_TXT_BASE=$(exec mktemp --suffix ".02.$PAGE_INDEX")

    echo "processing file $FILE, page $PAGE_INDEX"

    echo convert -monochrome -density "$RESOLUTION" "${FILE}[$(( PAGE_INDEX - 1 ))]" "$TEMP_TIF"  ## Just for debugging purposes.
    convert -monochrome -density "$RESOLUTION" "${FILE}[$(( PAGE_INDEX - 1 ))]" "$TEMP_TXT_BASE"

    tesseract "$TEMP_TIF" "$TEMP_TXT_BASE" -l ces

    echo "$PAGE_INDEX"$'\t'"${TEMP_TXT_BASE}.txt" >> "$TEMPLISTFILE"

    rm -f "$TEMP_TIF"
}

export -f convert_func

FILES=(/home/tgr/OCR/input/*.pdf)

for F in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    FILENAME=${F##*/}
    ENDPAGE=$(exec pdfinfo "$F" | grep '^Pages: *[0-9]\+$' | sed 's/.* //')
    BASENAME=${FILENAME%.*}
    OUTPUT="/home/tgr/OCR/output/$BASENAME.txt"
    RESOLUTION=1400

    TEMPLISTFILE=$(exec mktemp --suffix ".00.$BASENAME")
    : > "$TEMPLISTFILE"

    for (( I = 1; I <= ENDPAGE; ++I )); do
        printf "%s\xFF%s\xFF%s\xFF%s\x00" "$F" "$RESOLUTION" "$I" "$OUTPUT"
    done | parallel -0 -C $'\xFF' -j 4 -- convert_func '{1}' '{2}' '{3}' '{4}' "$TEMPLISTFILE"

    while IFS=$'\t' read -r __ FILE; do
        cat "$FILE"
        rm -f "$FILE"
    done < <(exec sort -n "$TEMPLISTFILE") > "$OUTPUT"

    rm -f "$TEMPLISTFILE"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, need some time to test it. Because multiple pages of single file are processed in parallel, what will ensure that OCR results of Page1 go into output file before OCR results of Page2?

Comment: @TomasGreif You need to use temporary files instead and only append the content of those temporary files to the main txt file when the page id is already away by 4 jobs. After the end of the loop as well, append the remaining temporary files.

Comment: I made an update. Apparently my idea was actually not possible to apply. This time files need to be held first before they are concatenated to one output.